# Angular Meteor publishComposite Emptiness

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm using angular-meteor and the cool publish-composite package. I have chats and under that I have related contacts. I'm storing contactIds in the chat document. I'm publishing like so:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('chats', function () {
 if (! this.userId) {
   return;
 }

 return {
  find: function() {
    return Chats.find({ userIds: this.userId });
  },
  children: [
    {
     collectionName: 'relatedContacts',
      find: function(chat) {
        let contactIds = [];
        if (chat.contactIds) {
          contactIds = chat.contactIds;
        }
        return Contacts.find({ _id: { $in: contactIds } });
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

});

Now, I'm trying to show my contacts in the view and it never seems to come back with anything. Here is my code:

```
RelatedContacts = new Mongo.Collection('relatedContacts');

var app = angular.module('MyApp').controller('ACtrl',
function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor) {

$scope.chat = $meteor.object(Chats, $stateParams.chatId);
$scope.contacts = RelatedContacts.find();
```

I'm not sure why it would be coming up blank. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I actually got this working. The chat object wasn't loaded before I tried to access the related docs.

Comment: are you using a wrap the code inside meteor.isServer() ?